# Unique ratios of integers

Tags: fractions, rational-numbers, ratio

If $m$ is an integer between $0$ and $M$ inclusive, and $n$ an integer between $0$ and $N$ inclusive, there are $(M+1)(N+1)$ non-unique values of $m/n$, including the undetermined form $0/0$ and infinity.  For instance, if $M=N=4$, then $2=2/1=4/2$ appears twice.

Is there some way to determine the unique values, and possibly the corresponding pairs of $m$ and $n$?

I am writing some brute-force code in python for this, but I fear mistakes because of numerical precision, when $M$ and $N$ are large (of the order of 25000).  The code will just iterate through all values of $m$ and $n$, compute the ratio, and look for duplicates.

Comment: To get started:   For each specified $n$ appearing in a reduced expression of the form $\frac mn<1$ all possible $m$ must be relatively prime to $n$.  there are exactly $\varphi(n)$ possible  such values of $m$.

Comment: Precision is not an issue for integer calculations, and if you are using floating-point calculations here, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks for tips, am looking into the [fractions module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html)